# I Can't style the size of my icons in Sencha Architect with html and css

Tags: html, css, extjs, font-awesome, sencha-architect

I was wondering why I can't seem to increase the size of my icon.

This is my config html:

```
<i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i>
```

in my stylesheet I'm doing this:

```
.fa-hand-o-up{
   color: white;
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

The color works but the `font-size` doesn't, can someone help me?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to figure out where the font-size for that element actually comes from, there’s likely a rule with higher specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.fa.fa-hand-o-up {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<i class="fa fa-hand-o-up" style="font-size:50px;color:white;"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does't do anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Try adding replace `font-size: 50px` line of your CSS by `font-size: 50px !important`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does't do anything :(

Answer (score 1):

To increase Font Awesome icon size you can use "fa-2x", "fa-3x",... classes:

```
<i class="fa fa-hand-o-up fa-2x"></i>
```

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/)

Comment: I already tried this because if i look it up, this is what is says but for some reason it does''t work